# Multiselect page from a lookup

Tags: apex, custom-field, picklist, multi-select

Is it possible to relate multiple records to a single lookup field (or) Is there a way to create a multiselect picklist/longtext field  and dynamically fill in a related object info in the picklist, where the user can have a clickable link to the record?

Please let me know if there is a hack to do this.

Comment: Serious question !!!I have never tried such stuff .Weekend excercise :)

Comment: why would you not model this relationship as a many to one. multiple contacts are related to the same account and you can click through to each via the related list or hover links ?

Answer (score 1):

If you went with a multi-select picklist you could use a formula field to generate the links.

Example formula field definition using a multi-select picklist:

```
IF(Includes( LinkSelect__c , "Google"),  HYPERLINK('http://google.com','google') ,"") & " " &
IF(Includes( LinkSelect__c , "Bing"),  HYPERLINK('http://bing.com','bing') ,"")
```

Things to consider:

- The Hyperlink function will work with fields so you can have dynamic data
- This approach requires hard-coding values for the comparison
- You can see more about Includes and Hyperlink in the [documentation](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions.htm)

Comment: How will I dynamically populate the data !!! say Account has 10 contacts I want to display the 10 contacts and the user can select from the multi select options( this is least desired cos this will be gluchy UI) a click on the lookup letting user select multiple records with ; seperated will be awesome to have. I can at the end of the day have a junction object and relate multiple contacts to an account, but wanted to know if there is a way to override the lookup and have it point to a VF page and pass back selected value to the standard page!!!

Comment: Multiple contacts are already related to Accounts (did you mean many-to-many?) If you want it to be dynamic you'll have to resort to Apex triggers. Those links could point to a VF page, but this sounds messy; you may want to rethink and simplify the implementation.

Comment: yep I think I will build a VF page and do and Inline embed with Accounts and show all related lists in tabbed fashion.Sales is always picky about moving to diff page,so this approach!!!!